# How do I specify the Python version in a NodeJS Heroku app?

Tags: python, node.js, heroku, version, child-process

I'm deploying a NodeJS app through Heroku and utilizing child processes to run some python scripts. I was facing a few syntax errors when the app was first deployed, and after a bit of digging, I found out the python version was 2.7.17 when I needed 3.8 or higher, which made me ask:

**How do I specify (or upgrade) the python version for a NodeJS app hosted on Heroku?**

After a little looking around I stumbled upon [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes), which obviously didn't work (else I wouldn't be here asking). I followed the steps and added a runtime.txt file containing "python-3.8.6" (one of the supported python versions by Heroku) but upon checking the python version, 2.7.17 appeared again. I'm assuming the solution linked above focuses on Django/python based servers and doesn't work on NodeJS deployments. Otherwise, I am likely forgetting/missing an important step, which I can't really see anywhere.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I've just as the documentation you linked to says put python-3.x in the runtime.txt. What version is it defaulting to?

Comment: The program defaults to 2.7.17* regardless of the runtime.txt file.

*I said 2.7.12 in the original post but meant 2.7.17, will fix that right now.

Comment: Strange. Does requirements.txt work? Is the file in the correct directory?

Comment: Sorry, I'm fairly new to this if it wasn't apparent. What exactly do you mean when you ask if "requirements.txt works"? I have requirements.txt and runtime.txt in the root directory of the project.

Comment: By that I mean if the libraries specified in requirements.txt are installed, as in if the file is read. You could try making a short program to check if they get installed in python 2.7

Comment: I figured it out, I was just not using buildpacks and was missing pipinstall in my procfile. Thanks for your help!